# What is the name of the connector which hakko soldering irons have

Tags: connector, soldering, identification

I would like to build a soldering station for a Hakko 907 soldering iron, but I don't know the name of the connector what I'm going to need.

[image]

Here is a link for the soldering iron that I have ordered:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/311188226034

- Can someone tell me what is the name of the female connector what I'm going to need?
- Is it possible to mount this connector onto the front panel of my case?

I saw similar connectors but all of them were made for cables, not for cases. Probably I saw completely different connectors.

Comment: From looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector it appears to be a DIN 45322.

Answer (score 4):

This looks similar to a circular [DIN connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector#Circular_connectors) (not to be confused with mini-DIN).

This type of connector existed for a long time.  Panel-mount female jacks for this type of connector do exist ([example](http://www.showmecables.com/product/5-pin-din-female-panel-mount-connector-240.aspx)).

[image]

Comment: It isn't a DIN connector, it has a central spigot.

Comment: @LeonHeller DINs with a central peg appear to exist as well.

Comment: I've never heard of one.

Comment: @LeonHeller What looks like a central locating pin is probably just the shell alignment dimple that is hard to identify in the picture.  Most TC soldering irons use pretty standard DIN connectors from what I have seen, the locking ring may have to be removed if you use a standard panel socket but is not required in practice.

Answer (score 2):

The Hakko part number for the panel connector is B2005 and should be available from them as a replaceable part.

Comment: Nice source if the price is reasonable, good find.

Comment: That looks like only the collar?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the connector is 5 pin `GX16 aviation connector`.